# Skinning an iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm building a clients IOS app and the brief requests that the end-user should be able to change the apps style theme - colors fonts etc - its a 5/6 page app with a variety of text fields, labels and text views as you would expect.

I'm reasonably new to IOS dev and predominately a front-end dev, so if this were a standard site I would simply define base CSS styles and apply to the relevant objects and switch programatically - I wondered whether there is a similar switchable approach to define base styles in IOS?

Or whether anyone has any suggestions?

Comment: no, there is nothing similar to CSS. You would have to implement your own 'skinning' mechanism

Comment: @user1567896 there are. Dancer have a look at https://github.com/tombenner/nui I have used this previously as a quick and cheap why of styling an app (I don't use this at work though just for playing with at home and have one app instore that has used this.) There is also http://nativecss.com/ which I haven't used

Comment: Oh... interesting :). But its not part of the official API.

Comment: @user1567896 What official API?

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is the [UIAppearance](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol.

You'll have to do a bit of work though. If you change the appearance you'll have to remove and re-add the view.